# Factoring $x^4+x^2+2x+6$

Tags: factoring

We have to factor $x^4+x^2+2x+6$.Factoring through factor theorem is not helpful in this question as the question does not follow the integral root theorem i.e. the root of this expression is not any of the factors of 6. I am totally confused.Please help in factoring it!

Comment: Could you describe the features of the polynomial to be factored suggesting to turn to the decomposition in the first RHS of the equation in the answer you accepted? Just curious...

Comment: Please do not modify the question after some answers are posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\begin{eqnarray}{\bf Hint}\quad x^4\!+x^2\!+2x+6\, &=& \qquad x^4 + 4 &+& x^2\!+2x+2\\
&=&\!\! (x^2\!+\!2)^2\!\!-(2x)^2 &+& x^2\!+2x+2\\
&=&\!\! (x^2\!+\!2 -2x)(\color{#c00}{x^2\!+2 + 2x})\!\! &+& \color{#c00}{x^2\!+2x+2}\\
&=&\!\! (x^2\!-2x+3)(\color{#c00}{x^2\!+ 2x\! + 2})\!\!\!\
\end{eqnarray}$

Comment: @BillDubuque Thankx for your.Can you plz also help me factorize the expression if instead of $x^4+x^2+2x+6$ it is $x^4+x^2+2x-6$

Comment: What suggests to turn to the decomposition in the first RHS?

Comment: Previous comments by the OP (now unfortunately deleted) referred to so-called *Aurifeuillian* decompositions as the key to understand the decomposition of $x^4+x^2+2x+6$ in the RHS of the first line of this answer (see [here](http://www.dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/PDF/AureFinal.pdf) for an introduction to this notion). Some further explanations might be needed to substantiate this intriguing claim.

Comment: @JiK One elementary way to quickly factor it is as a slight perturbation of well-known factorizations
$\tag*{}$
$\qquad\!\! x^4+x^2-6\, =\, \underbrace{x^4-4}_{g^{\phantom{I}}}\ +\ \underbrace{x^2- 2}_{f^{\phantom{I}}}\quad\ $ and $\,f\,$ divides $\,g\,$ by Classical Difference of Squares
$x^4\!+x^2\!+2x\!+6\, =\, \overbrace{x^4\!+\!4} + \overbrace{x^2\!+\!2x\!+\!2}\ $ and $\,f\,$ divides $\,g\,$ by [Complete to Difference of Squares](http://goo.gl/pk2Ey0)
$\tag*{}$
Hence the second factorization is as obvious as the first if one is familiar with the well-known factorization of $\,x^4\! + 4\ $

Answer (score 8):

The polynomial $x^4+x^2+2x+6$ is $x^4+(x+1)^2+5\geqslant5$ for every $x$ hence it has no real root. Thus, there is no factor of degree $1$ hence one can only have two factors of degree $2$, that is, the factorization to be found is $$x^4+x^2+2x+6=(x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d),$$ for some $(a,b,c,d)$. The coefficients of $x^3$ and $x^0$ in the product on the RHS should be $0$ and $6$ respectively hence $a+c=0$ and $bd=6$, which brings us to $$x^4+x^2+2x+6=(x^2+ax+b)(x^2-ax+6/b).$$ Since the coefficients of $x$ and $x^2$ in this product should be $2$ and $1$ respectively, this yields two equations in $(a,b)$.

Can you write these down and see what happens?

Comment: Nominally, those equations have a lot of solutions - up to $\binom 4 2=6$ complex solutions and at least $2$ real solutions, so being two equations in 2 variables isn't enough to ensure an easy solution.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes. Fortunately these have integer solutions (a,b) hence we are saved...

Comment: And since you know it is positive, you know that $b$ is positive. Assuming integers, then you can just look for solutions where $b=1,2$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Indeed.

Answer (score 4):

$$x^4+x^2+2x+6=x^4+2ax^2+a^2-\left( (2a-1)x^2-2x+a^2-6 \right)$$

Now, $\left( (2a-1)x^2-2x+a^2-6 \right)$  is a constant times perfect square if and only if $\Delta =0$ if and only if
$$4-4(2a-1)(a^2-6)=0$$
if and only if
$$(2a-1)(a^2-6)=1$$

Factoring and using the rational root test you will find that $a=\frac{5}{2}$ is (the only) rational root.

With this choice of $a$, your polynomial becomes a difference of squares.

Comment: This works to find the factorization of $x^4+px^2+2qx+r$ if and only if $2a^3-pa^2-2ra+pr-q^2=0$, hence one wonders when this has easy $a$ solutions. +1.

Comment: You wrote that $\left( (2a-1)x^2-2x+a^2-6 \right)$is a constant times perfect square if and only if Δ=0.Can you please explain me what does $\Delta$ denote here.

Comment: @SNEHILSINHA $\Delta$ is the discriminant of the quadratic function. If $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ is a quadratic function, $\Delta=b^2-4ac$.

Comment: @N.S. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in $ \mathbb{R}$, note that $p(x)=x^2+2x+6$ and $q(x)=x^4$ are always positive if $x\neq 0$, so its sum is also positive. This means the polynomial has no linear factors.

Comment: This doesn't mean that the polynomial has no non-trivial factors, though. In fact every fourth-degree polynomial over $\mathbb R$ can be factorised as a product of real quadratic polynomials (also over $\mathbb R$).

Comment: @TonyK Thanks for the comment.

Comment: You mean "no linear factors", not "no trivial factors". A trivial factor is something like $99$, or $x^4/2 + x^2/2 + x + 3$. Every polynomial has trivial factors.